# Compiler error when trying to throw a checked exception

Tags: java

With this code:

```java
  @Override
  public void transactPersistentEntityStore(String dir,
      StoreTransactionalExecutable txn) {
    final PersistentEntityStore entityStore =
        getPersistentEntityStore(dir);
    entityStore.executeInTransaction(txn);
  }
```

How can it throw an exception inside the lambda:
*(This code throws a compiler error)*

```java
Database database = Database.getInstance();
database.transactPersistentEntityStore(application.getDir(), 
    txn -> {
        // Compiler error:
        throw new Exception("Something wrong");
    });
```

**StoreTransactionalExecutable.java** code from a Java library:

```java
public interface StoreTransactionalExecutable {
    void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn);
}
```

Comment: The issue here has nothing to do with a lambda.  Checked exceptions must be either caught or declared.  You've done neither, so the compiler throws an error.  This is the definition of a checked exception.  Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong the question may not explicitly state it but it is clearly about propagating the exception from the lambda so it can be cause from outside the lambda.

Comment: @quarks The advice is still the same.  Checked exceptions have to be caught or declared.  Whether you use a lambda or not, there's no way around that.  If you want to propagate the exception back up the stack, you would need to stick a `throws` clause in the functional interface.  Looks like the OP's interface is from the Java library, though, so that might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way is to let lambda throw some `RuntimeException` in a try/catch and throw the a checked exception having this `RuntimeException` as a cause. So something like:

```
try {
    database.transactPersistentEntityStore(application.getDir(), 
        txn -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something wrong");
        });
} catch (RuntimeException rte) {
    throw new SomeCheckedException(rte);
}
```